# Steady-error for step input and ramp input

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, control-theory

I have a closed loop system and my transfer function is:

T1 =

```
 ((s^2 + 9)*(s - 10)) / ((s^3 + 11)*(s^2 - 2)*(s - 10))
```

How I can calculate the steady-state error for T1 when the input is:
1) step 
2) ramp

is there a direct command in matlab to do that?

Comment: How about `step(T1)`?

Comment: I have tried using this command: [y,t,x] = step(T1); but I get an empty x

Comment: Yes, `x` are the state trajectories if you have a state space model (which you don't have here). You can start with simply `step(T1)` and visually check the step response. Then you can use `[y,t]` where `y` is the step response and `t` the time vector to calculate the error.

Comment: So I should compare the output y to the time t? or what if I convert my transfer function to state space so that I can get x and compare it to y. Which method is more accurate in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

The step and ramp signals have Laplace transforms of `1/s` and `1/s^2`. To have the output you multiply this with your plant transfer function which gives you the output laplace transform. But your system has a pole/zero cancellation at `10`, first get rid of that (as if we didn't notice from the common factor).

```
s = tf('s')
G = ((s^2 + 9)*(s - 10)) / ((s^3 + 11)*(s^2 - 2)*(s - 10))
Gm = minreal(G);
% Clean up the numerical noise
Gm.num{1}(5) = 0;
Gm.den{1}(2) = 0;
Gm.den{1}(5) = 0;
```

This is your minimal system, and from the poles of it

```
>> eig(Gm)
ans =
   1.1120 + 1.9260i
   1.1120 - 1.9260i
   1.4142          
  -2.2240          
  -1.4142
```

we see that it is unstable. Hence, the step steady state error, which is the limit of the expression `Gm*1/s` when `s->0` is infinity. Similarly the same answer is given with ramp. Your closed loop is unstable.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. well first of all my original planet and controller  are:

P = (s+10)/(s*(s-1));       % Plant
C = ((s-1)/(s+11));         % Controller
The planet is not stable since I have a positive pole at 1. So I made my controller to cancel that positive pole but when I built my open loop and closed loop transfer function matlab does not cancel